# Is there a was to resale woo commerce sold products after a month?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I need help to know about any WordPress plugin or code snippet that allows to put sold items for sale after 30 days.
e.g. I have sold a Pen today at my website, now after 30 days it is again available for sale automatically.
Thanks all!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since all products will get outofstock at different period of time we need to konw when they get sold out. For that we need to save this date as additional meta. We may have variable products so then we need to save per variation too. If all products will be with same stock and not overcomplicating it then you can use this as a starting point - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/346781/187933.  After that we need a cron job that will update the quantity of products sold out before X days. Its not a simple as it seems so hire someone to do it for you if plugin is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin appears to do what you want. Note that I haven't used it personally!
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-schedule-stock-manager/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I need to re-sale the products after 30 days of their sale. This plugin does not seem to schedule the stock quantity updation for sold items only. Please help if I am missing something. Thanks